# Get url parameter from Service Provider in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Normally in Laravel you get a request bag with all parameters in it. But in a service provider this is not the case. But we do have the `request()` object.

However, this does not contain the url parameters given in the resource routing.

So what I'm looking for is a way to retrieve the {id} from the route.

I have tried:

```
request()->route('id')
Route::get('id')
Request::get('id')
```

All of these return null

Comment: Could you provide the code for your provider? So that we see what it is you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: No code is needed in my opinion. I just want to get a parameter in a Service provider. I do not need a workaround, cause I already have one implemented.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both **boot()** and **register()** methods of any service provider are called before request is parsed and request parameters are known, that's why you can't access them.

Service providers are supposed to register services and shouldn't depend on the request context. If you want to use request parameters in your services, declare **request** service as a dependency of your service so that it's injected the moment your service gets instantiated.