# access to parameter in a wildcard laravel sub domain in included blade template

Tags: php, laravel

I have a wildcard sub domain definition like this in my **laravel** project:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{website}.' . config('app.url')], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'wb-homepage', 'uses' => 'WebsiteController@homePage']);
        Route::get('/AdsAll', ['uses' => 'WebsiteController@AdsAll']);
});
```

All routes that is defined under that route group are contain a `header.blade.php` that I want to access value of {website} parameter that is that is defined as subdomain.

One of way that I think can access that parameter was `boot ()` of `AppServiceProvider.php` . I tried different ways that but according [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764406/get-url-parameter-from-service-provider-in-laravel)  I could not use it beacause :

*Both boot() and register() methods of any service provider are called before request is parsed and request parameters are known, that's why you can't access them*

Now my question is that what is proper way to access `website` parameter in a included blade template?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using `5.4.36`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware) global middleware for this and [share](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) the data with all of your views.

Firstly, to create the middleware you can run:

```
php artisan make:middleware ShareSiteSubdomain
```

Then in the `ShareSiteSubdomain` add:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    view()->share('website', $request->route('website'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

Lastly, go to your `app/Http/Kernel.php` and add `\App\Http\Middleware\ShareSiteSubdomain::class` to `web` array in the `$middlewareGroups` array.

Then you should have a variable called `$website` available in all of your views.

Comment: What about If I want that variable in an specific blade ?

Comment: @A.B.Developer The you can use view composers instead (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers).